# MongoDb : Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback on remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb

using MongoDB w node.js, I am trying to remove an item after finding it .. but it's failing

1. I get the collection  (db.collection)
2. I find the item ( collection.findOne )
3. I remove the item from the collection

what's wrong in my script ?

```
exports.revokeRefreshToken = function (refreshToken,  callback) {
  db.collection('oauth_refresh_tokens', function(err, collection) {
    collection.findOne({'refreshToken': refreshToken}, function(err, item) {
        db.collection('oauth_refresh_tokens').remove({_id: item._id});
        callback(err );
    });
 });
```

};

Comment: The error suggests you need to specify a callback for remove. It doesn't look like you've got one.

Comment: thanks , I modified the function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified the revoke function to include a callback

```
exports.revokeRefreshToken = function (refreshToken,  callback) {
  db.collection('oauth_refresh_tokens', function(err, collection) {
      collection.remove({'refreshToken': refreshToken} , function(err, result) {
          callback(err);
      });
  });
};
```